# How to program to prevent the Windows "Not Responding" dialog

Tags: c++, mfc

When an application fails to be responsive for 5 seconds ([source](https://superuser.com/a/961910/138951)), Windows can display "(Not Responding)" in the title bar and in some cases show a "not responding" dialog:

[image: Not Responding dialog]

Ideally, the 5+ second execution should not block the main/event-processing thread, but is there a simple (e.g. 1 liner for MFC C++) way to communicate to Windows that the main thread is busy and shouldn't be treated as a "Not Responding" application to be closed?  Is the quickest hack to simply periodically call peak [PeekMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `PM_NOREMOVE`?

Comment: If you had a flat tire, would you like to replace it, or drive around town with an air pump attached? **don't do heavy processing in your main/gui thread**.

Comment: If you have long-running operations that block the message pump, the best solution is to have a worker thread that allows the main thread to keep working and not wait.

Comment: @Amit, yes, I agree, but suppose you have an old truck that has dozens of flat tires and you can only afford one new tire a week.  Please let me know if there is a pump somewhere to use as a crutch while I try to overcome the technical debt.

Comment: If you can't spawn a new thread for some reason, but you can break the long-running task down into smaller parts, you can do the processing in [`CWinApp::OnIdle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e077sxt.aspx). This function gets called from within the message pump loop whenever there are no Windows messages waiting, which means the messages are handled at a higher priority. This keeps your window from going unresponsive, as long as the processing you do in `OnIdle` takes a reasonably short time per call.

Comment: That answer you mention is downvoted to the bottom because it's very bad advice - it solves the immediate problem of showing an error message but leaves you with a window that acts completely dead.

Comment: @MarkRansom I agree with you, and I thought this was clear by my labeling it as a "Quick Hack Fix For A Terrible UX".  I find it odd that someone went through the trouble of editing my question to hide this information as if Stack Overflow users can't handle the truth.

Comment: That edit wasn't a lot of trouble - there's a "revert" button on each version of the question that makes it automatic. If you want to play edit wars, you can hit that button too.

Comment: It sounds like you are doing something in sequence, and you just want the user to be able to move the window during that few seconds. You are probably prepared to handle cancel/close, while other controls are disabled. So in this case `PeekMessage` is fine. You can use `while(PeekMessage(... PM_NOREMOVE)) AfxGetThread()->PumpMessage();` It's not a cheat or hack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There really are no hacks to solve this. Any monkeying about with the message pump can lead to all manner of disaster, especially with COM and other system message processing.

Don't hold up the main thread.

Move the longer running tasks to a background or worker thread and either poll a future for completion or have the thread post a message back to the GUI to signal it is complete and then retrieve the result required.

Answer (score 4):

In Windows 3.1 world all those eons ago, the answer was to divide your work into short-duration chunks, run the chunks in your window's message procedure and go from chunk to chunk by calling `PostMessage`.

Nowadays you update the window to show that the work is in progress, spawn a thread and call some PostMessage equivalent at the end of the thread so that your window can update itself back and show the results.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no quick hack, because your app is indeed not responding if you use the main thread like that.