# A window transparent overlay stops working after a few seconds

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, directx, overlay

I'm trying to create a transparent overlay over some process' window (I want to draw some stuff on the overlay using Direct3D 9).

The overlay is being created by using an external program (not a .dll injected library or something).

The problem is when I launch the program, an invisible overlay appears over the process window (and it even draws some text on it, so the WM_PAINT seems to be working), but in the next few seconds the cursor becomes a "sand clock" styled (sorry, I don't know how else is it called xd) and if I click on the window, it shows an error "The app is not responding" and becomes solid white.
[image: "the app is not responding" message]

I import the overlay class into the entry point file and here's how I run it in the main function (simplified):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "memory.hpp"
#include "overlay.hpp"

int main() {
    Memory mem;
    Overlay ol(&mem);
    HANDLE overlay = CreateThread(NULL, NULL, &ol.static_start, (void*)&ol, NULL, NULL);

    while (1) {
        SendMessage(ol.hwnd, WM_PAINT, NULL, NULL);

        Sleep(2);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

overlay.hpp:

```cpp
#ifndef OVERLAY_HPP
#define OVERLAY_HPP
#pragma once
 
#include <Windows.h>
#include <d3d9.h>
#include "paint.hpp" // has a class with methods to draw on overlay using d3dx9
#include "memory.hpp" // has a tHWND variable - handle to target window 
#include <iostream>
#include <dwmapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "dwmapi.lib")
 
Paint paint;
 
class Overlay {
private:
    WCHAR _title[20] = L"anoverlay"; // overlay window title
    // HINSTANCE hwnd_inst;
    Memory* mem;
    RECT rect; // coordinates of target window
 
    // registers window class
    ATOM _register_сlass() {
        WNDCLASSEX wc;
        ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
 
        wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
        wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
        wc.cbClsExtra = NULL;
        wc.cbWndExtra = NULL;
        wc.hInstance = reinterpret_cast<HINSTANCE>(GetWindowLongW(mem->tHWND, GWL_HINSTANCE)); // hwnd_inst;
        wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
        wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
        wc.hbrBackground = WHITE_BRUSH;
        wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
        wc.lpszClassName = _title;
        wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);;
 
        return RegisterClassEx(&wc);
    }
 
    // initialise overlay instance
    bool _init_instance(int width, int height) {
        hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_LAYERED, _title, _title, WS_POPUP, rect.left, rect.top, width, height, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (!hwnd) return false;
 
        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, 0, 1.0f, LWA_ALPHA);
        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, 0, RGB(0, 0, 0), LWA_COLORKEY);
 
        MARGINS _margins = { -1, -1, -1, -1 };
        DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hwnd, &_margins);
 
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
        return true;
    }
 
public:
    HWND hwnd; // an HWND to the overlay window
 
    Overlay(Memory* mem) {
        this->mem = mem;
        if (!init()) std::cout << "The overlay window was not created" << std::endl;
    }
 
    ~Overlay() {
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
    }
 
    bool init() {
        if (!mem->tHWND) return false;
        if (!GetWindowRect(mem->tHWND, &rect)) return false;
        _register_сlass();
 
        if (!_init_instance(rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top)) return false;
        paint = Paint(hwnd, mem->tHWND, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top);
 
        return true;
    }
 
    DWORD APIENTRY start() {
        MSG msg;
 
        while (true) {
            if (PeekMessage(&msg, hwnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
                if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) break;
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
 
                GetWindowRect(mem->tHWND, &rect);
                int width = rect.right - rect.left;
                int height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
 
                MoveWindow(hwnd, rect.left, rect.top, width, height, true);
            }
            Sleep(1);
        }
 
        return (int)msg.wParam;
    }
 
    static DWORD WINAPI static_start(void* param) {
        Overlay* ol = (Overlay*)param;
        return ol->start();
    }
 
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
        switch (message) {
        case WM_PAINT:
            paint.render();
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        return 0;
    }
};
#endif
```

memory.hpp:

```cpp
#ifndef MEMORY_HPP
#define MEMORY_HPP
 
#pragma once
#pragma warning(disable: 6276)
 
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
 
const wchar_t* TARGET = L"Telegram.exe"; // you may put any program here, like Notepad or Calculator
LPCSTR WINDOW_NAME = "Telegram";
 
class Memory {
public:
    DWORD tPID;
    HANDLE tProcess;
    HWND tHWND;
 
    Memory() {
        this->tPID = NULL;
        this->tProcess = NULL;
 
        if (!this->handle_process(TARGET)) return;
        this->tHWND = FindWindowA(0, WINDOW_NAME);
    }
 
    ~Memory() {
        CloseHandle(tProcess);
    }
 
    HANDLE handle_process(const wchar_t* processName) {
        HANDLE handle = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);
        PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
        entry.dwSize = sizeof(entry);
 
        do {
            if (!wcscmp(entry.szExeFile, processName)) {
                tPID = entry.th32ProcessID;
                CloseHandle(handle);
                tProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, tPID);
                return tProcess;
            }
        } while (Process32Next(handle, &entry));
        CloseHandle(handle);
        return NULL;
    }
};
#endif
```

paint.hpp:

```cpp
#ifndef PAINT_HPP
#define PAINT_HPP
#pragma once
#pragma warning(disable: 26495)
 
#include <Windows.h>
 
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h> // Project -> [project name] Properties -> VC++ Directories: Add $(DXSDK_DIR)Include into Include Directories and $(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x86 into Library directories
// Make sure you have Direct3D 9 SDK installed - https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=6812
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d9.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3dx9.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "legacy_stdio_definitions.lib")
 
class Paint {
private:
    IDirect3D9Ex* object = NULL; // used to create device
    IDirect3DDevice9Ex* device = NULL; // contains functions like begin and end scene 
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS params;
    ID3DXFont* d3d_font = 0; // font used when displaying text
 
    HWND t_hwnd; // target process window
    int width; // target process width
    int height;
 
    int d3d9init(HWND hwnd) {
        if (FAILED(Direct3DCreate9Ex(D3D_SDK_VERSION, &object))) {
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        }
 
        ZeroMemory(&params, sizeof(params));
        params.BackBufferWidth = width;
        params.BackBufferHeight = height;
        params.Windowed = TRUE;
        params.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
        params.hDeviceWindow = hwnd;
        params.MultiSampleQuality = D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONE;
        params.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8;
        params.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
        params.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;
 
        HRESULT res = object->CreateDeviceEx(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, hwnd, D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &params, 0, &device);
        if (FAILED(res)) DestroyWindow(hwnd);
 
        D3DXCreateFont(device, 50, 0, FW_BOLD, 1, false, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_DEVICE_PRECIS, ANTIALIASED_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH, L"Consolas", &d3d_font);
 
        return 0;
    }
 
    void draw_text(char* text, int x, int y, int a, int r, int g, int b) {
        RECT rect;
        rect.left = x;
        rect.top = y;
        d3d_font->DrawTextA(0, text, strlen(text), &rect, DT_NOCLIP, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(a, r, g, b));
    }
 
public:
    Paint() {
        this->device = nullptr;
        this->object = nullptr;
    }
 
    ~Paint() {
        if (object != NULL) object->Release();
        if (device != NULL) device->Release();
    }
 
    Paint(HWND hwnd, HWND t_hwnd, int width, int height) {
        this->t_hwnd = t_hwnd;
        this->width = width;
        this->height = height;
        d3d9init(hwnd);
    }
 
    int render() {
        if (device == nullptr) return 1;
 
        device->Clear(0, 0, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, 0, 1.0f, 0);
        device->BeginScene();
 
        if (t_hwnd == GetForegroundWindow()) {
            draw_text((char*)"Test message", 15, 15, 255, 150, 150, 150);
        }
 
        device->EndScene();
        device->PresentEx(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
 
        return 0;
    }
};
 
#endif
```

It just does not work correctly. Any ideas, what am I doing wrong?
Also I've noticed a strange thing, that when I try to debug, it gives me an error "0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xADE50000" at the point where I call the RegisterClassEx (overlay.hpp) function. So strange, even though I initialised all the members of the WNDCLASSEX structure. Also it's quite strange that the project builds successfully and I can run the builded .exe file.

Comment: Asking the same question over and over is not cool. You still are not running a message loop in your main thread. You weren't in the last question. You aren't now.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I've asked the same question because mods closed last one, even though I edited what they wanted me to edit.
Honestly, I don't understand what do you mean by saying I'm not running the message loop in the main thread. I running it in another thread and sending messages there from the main thread. I can't put the message loop into the main thread because I already have lots of loops and statements in original program. 
Also the program works well on other commenter's PC. Maybe the problem is with my IDE or smth? But I'll anyway try to put the message loop into main thread.

Comment: [About Messages and Message Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the access conflict is the setting of the `hInstance` parameter in your `WNDCLASSEX` structure. You can set it to `GetModuleHandle(NULL)`;

Just like the code :

```
wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
```

The reason why the application is not responding is that you set the GUI thread in the thread, and set the wireless loop in the main thread, which will cause the UI thread to not respond. You can refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51567053/how-to-provoke-application-not-responding).

You just need to call the `start` function in the main thread, and then create a thread to execute the `SendMessage` function can solve this problem:

```
void fun(const Overlay&ol)
{
    while (1) {
        SendMessage(ol.hwnd, WM_PAINT, NULL, NULL);
    }
}

int main() {
    Memory mem;
    Overlay ol(&mem);
    std::thread t(fun, ol);
    ol.static_start(&ol);
    //HANDLE overlay = CreateThread(NULL, NULL, &ol.static_start, (void*)&ol, NULL, NULL);
    

    t.join();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Edit**

As @David said, You should not send the `WM_PAINT` message, just call the `start` function directly to work properly.

Comment: You can't send WM_PAINT messages

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, after testing, I found that the function to send the `WM_PAINT` message is redundant and can be deleted directly. I wrote this to explain the reason why the application did not respond.

Comment: Thank you, @ZhuSong-MSFT, it works. Also could you please tell me why exactly shouldn't I send WM_PAINT messages from the parallel thread?

Comment: @Andrew The system will be responsible for sending the `WM_PAINT` message. I tested that the code can also work normally without using another thread to send the `WM_PAINT`. You can refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365802/sending-message-to-wm-paint).

Comment: @ZhuSong-MSFT, thank you for your help, I appreciate it.
The problem is that I need the overlay thread to work in parallel with the main thread (i.e. calling the overlay thread does not block the execution of the code that follows it), because I want to send messages from the main code (using SendMessage) as well as do other work.

Comment: If you want to add an infinite loop and send messages in the main thread, there is no good way. Refer to @Niall's answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33135180/13566062): Move the longer running tasks to a background or worker thread and either poll a future for completion or have the thread post a message back to the GUI to signal it is complete and then retrieve the result required.